# iptables - dropping specific established connections after X hours

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, port-forwarding

Is there a way with iptables to drop specific established connections after X hours?

We have an application with limited connection support, and occasionally we see some tcp sessions that shouldn't be established for longer than a few seconds, usually hanging around indefinitely when it happens (perhaps some odd network issue).  This causes the app to block future requests :(

Since the box is doing port forwarding to the remote application, I figured I could just get iptables to drop these bad sessions, but I can't seem to find a way of doing that for a specific host/port combo (rather than the global conntrack timeout which would affect other things).

Comment: How do you define "that aren't needed"? iptables cannot make this distinction.

Comment: A host/port combo that has been established for X hours.

Comment: @AndyC This is something you should implement on the app side rather than trying other unsuitable ways.

Comment: @XavierLucas yes I agree, if it was possible to do so, but it is not unfortunately.

Comment: @AndyC Then you just can't do that at all.